# Copy and resize image with php GD library

Tags: php, php-gd

I want to copy, resize and (if it is not too hard) crop an image.

For example: I have an image with the dimensions 1200 height X 2300 width. I want to make an 100x100 pixels thumbnail of it, and in this case, because the height is less than the width the height should be 100% visible on the new image, and the width should keep the aspect ratio of the image. [Here is an example image](http://grona.co.cc/example.jpg).

Additional details:

I am using wamp, Ihave enabled Gd 2
I just get broken images when I try rewriting the code from the [example on this site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

Answer (score 1):

try this one its from the [Resize Images Using PHP and GD Library](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.in/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html)  article

```
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH', 150);
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT', 150);

function generate_image_thumbnail($source_image_path, $thumbnail_image_path)
{
    list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
    switch ($source_image_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
            break;
    }
    if ($source_gd_image === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $source_aspect_ratio = $source_image_width / $source_image_height;
    $thumbnail_aspect_ratio = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    if ($source_image_width <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH && $source_image_height <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width;
        $thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height;
    } elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
        $thumbnail_image_height = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    } else {
        $thumbnail_image_width = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH;
        $thumbnail_image_height = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
    }
    $thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
    imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: this thing needs refactoring ... desperately

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [Timthumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/)? It's a nice little script that matches your requirements.
If you get corrupted image files something with your GD installation might be wrong, but without seeing any code it's hard to guess. Do you have any other machine (maybe a webhost with LAMP stack) to test your code there?